# Nodejs passport, not getting user object in route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgdEHhUR3ag)

**Auth.js**

```
var passport = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done){
        console.log("----", username, password, "----"); //this works fine, get the proper values here.
        if(username === "admin" && password === "sw") {
            return done(null, {username: "admin"});
        }

        return done(null, false);
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done){
    done(null, {username: username});
});

module.exports = passport;
```

**app.js (the relevant bits)**

```
var passport = require("./auth")
var users = require('./routes/users');
.
.
.
app.use('/users', users);
app.post('/', passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/",
    successRedirect: "/users"
}));
```

**user route**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.user);
  res.render('users', {
    title: 'Routed !'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Most of the code works fine, it posts and routes correctly, but, `req.user` is `undefined` in the users route, and I'm not able to figure out why.

Comment: Which session store are you using? Also, how are you testing (the client you use should send the session cookie that gets set after a successful login)?

Comment: using `passport.session()`, I get an `undefined` on `req.session` in my user route.

Comment: You also need to use [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) if you want your user credentials to be propagated across multiple requests (make sure to use it _before_ `passport.session()`)

Comment: @robertklep that works !! thanks, why doesn't `passport.session` work though?

Comment: `passport.session()` is how Passport interacts with "regular" Express sessions, it doesn't implement generic sessions by itself.

Comment: @robertklep thanks :)